# Sending multiple sha1 checksums in a single file?

Tags: sha

I'm working on an application that needs to verify a large number of files that have been transferred over the web. Our current thinking is to put the checksums for multiple files into a single file and name is foobar.sha1

I have some hesitation about using this extension as it seems to mostly be used for communicating a single checksum (as opposed to a large batch). Is this common usage?

Google has not yielded a clear answer.

Thanks